# android imageloader and imageview scaletype

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

[image: this is my image]I have an imageview element into relativelayout with textView like this

```
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:background="@color/darkblue"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
android:paddingBottom="2dp"
android:gravity="bottom"
  android:paddingLeft="2dp"
  android:paddingRight="2dp"
   android:textSize="13sp"
   android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
     />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to load the image using imageloader, but when i load the image the height of image does not fill all the relative layout, i try to use scaletype: fitcenter and still not working, i try to change the height of image pro grammatically but still not showing all height,

```
    image.getLayoutParams().height=(int) (screenWidth/2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`
[here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html) u can read more about this